# Send stdin to bash process in docker container

Tags: docker, containers

Say I have:

```
ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

and I start the container:

```
docker run -d -it foo
```

is there a way to write to the stdin of the bash process in the container?

Comment: A much more typical setup would be to `COPY` a shell script into the image and set it as the default `CMD` of the container.  I wouldn't use `ENTRYPOINT` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either avoid detaching from the container when you create it, or you can attach to an already running container. In each case, an EOF on the input that you send in will be an EOF to bash which will cause the container to exit.

Remove the `-d` to avoid detaching:

```
docker run -it foo
```

Attach to a running container:

```
docker run -d -it --name bar foo
docker attach -it bar
```

Comment: so I can run `echo "foo" | docker run -t foo`, I should have tried that but I didn't expect that to work

Comment: The `-i` flag is required, it indicates stdin is configured for the container process.